# How to call custom decorator define on in blueprint to another in Flask application

Tags: python

I want to call the decorator define in on blueprint to another
Blueprintone.py

```
from flask import jsonify, Blueprint, current_app, request
import pyodbc
import logging

authenticate = Blueprint('authenticate', __name__)

#Custom decorator for token
def validateToken(token):
    return token+"true"
    
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):

        token = None

        if 'x-access-tokens' in request.headers:
            token = request.headers['x-access-tokens']
            #response=authenticate.validateToken(token)
            #print("response="+response)
            print(token)

        if not token:
            print("Access token is not pass")
            return json.dumps({'message': 'a valid token is missing'})

        try:
            current_user="true"
            #data = jwt.decode(token, app.config[SECRET_KEY])
            #current_user = Users.query.filter_by(public_id=data['public_id']).first()
            #return jsonify({'message': 'token is valid'})
        except:
            return json.dumps({'message': 'token is invalid'})

        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

Blueprinttwo.py

```
from flask import json, Blueprint, current_app,request
import pyodbc
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import collections
import logging
from functools import wraps
from blueprinttwo import token_required

desktop_demo = Blueprint('desktop_demo', __name__)
@token_required
@desktop_demo.route('/demo/<obj_list>/<user_id>/<session_id>', defaults={'user_id': None, 'session_id': None}, methods = ['GET'])

def demoStory(obj_list,user_id,session_id):
return true
```

I want to call @token_required decorator from blueprintone to inside blueprinttwo but it is giving error token_required is not define

Comment: You should include what error you are getting. For starters: you don't import it in `Blueprinttwo.py`

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your decorator to use it:

```
from Blueprintone import token_required
```